# How can I match two strings in a single foreach?

Tags: c#, regex, foreach

I'm using Regex to match characters from a file, but I want to match 2 different strings from that file but they appear more than once, that's why I am using a loop. I can match with a single string but not with 2 strings.

```
Regex celcius = new Regex(@"""temp"":\d*\.?\d{1,3}"); 
foreach (Match match in celcius.Matches(htmlcode))
{ 
    Regex date = new Regex(@"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}");
    foreach (Match match1 in date.Matches(htmlcode))
    {
        string date1 = Convert.ToString(match1.Value);
        string temperature = Convert.ToString(match.Value);
        Console.Write(temperature + "\t" + date1);
    }
}
```

**htmlcode:**

```
{"temp":287.05,"temp_min":286.932,"temp_max":287.05,"pressure":1019.04,"sea_level":1019.04,"grnd_level":1001.11,"humidity":89,"temp_kf":0.12},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast
clouds","icon":"04n"}],"clouds":{"all":100},"wind":{"speed":0.71,"deg":205.913},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2019-09-22
21:00:00"},{"dt":1569196800,"main":{"temp":286.22,"temp_min":286.14,"temp_max":286.22,"pressure":1019.27,"sea_level":1019.27,"grnd_level":1001.49,"humidity":90,"temp_kf":0.08},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast
clouds","icon":"04n"}],"clouds":{"all":99},"wind":{"speed":0.19,"deg":31.065},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2019-09-23
00:00:00"},{"dt":1569207600,"main":{"temp":286.04,"temp_min":286,"temp_max":286.04,"pressure":1019.38,"sea_level":1019.38,"grnd_level":1001.03,"humidity":89,"temp_kf":0.04},"weather":
```

Comment: Use an OR (|) inside your regex?

Comment: Please provide an example of the input text `htmlcode`.

Comment: `@"""temp"":\d*\.?\d{1,3}"` looks like you are parsing JSON with regex

Comment: If a for loop suits the problem better it is better to use a for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a single Regex pattern with two capturing groups for temperature and date. The pattern can look something like this:

```regex
("temp":\d*\.?\d{1,3}).*?(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VEtiV9/1).

**C# example:**

```
string htmlcode = // ...
var matches = Regex.Matches(htmlcode, @"(""temp"":\d*\.?\d{1,3}).*?(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})");
foreach (Match m in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value + "\t" + m.Groups[2].Value);
}
```

**Output:**

```
"temp":287.05   2019-09-22
"temp":286.22   2019-09-23
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/YDKOY33061).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have HTML. I think you have a collection of something called JSON (JavaScript Object Notification) which is a way to pass data efficiently.

So, this is one of your "HTML" objects.

```
{
    "temp":287.05,
    "temp_min":286.932,
    "temp_max":287.05,
    "pressure":1019.04,
    "sea_level":1019.04,
    "grnd_level":1001.11,
    "humidity":89,
    "temp_kf":0.12},
    "weather":[{
        "id":804,
        "main":"Clouds",
        "description":"overcast clouds",
        "icon":"04n"
    }],
    "clouds":{
        "all":100
    },
    "wind":{
        "speed":0.71,"deg":205.913
    },
    "sys":{
        "pod":"n"
    },
    "dt_txt":"2019-09-22 21:00:00"
}
```

So, I would recommend converting the line using the C# web helpers and parsing the objects directly.

```
//include this library
using System.Web.Helpers;

//parse your htmlcode using this loop
foreach(var line in htmlcode)
{
    dynamic data = JSON.decode(line);
    string temperature = (string)data["temp"];
    string date = Convert.ToDateTime(data["dt_txt"]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Console.WriteLine($"temperature: {temperature} date: {date}"");
}
```